# Logging mysql results with timings

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli, profiling

I'm using MySql 5.0.37 on my server and I'm able to get profiling data when I use `set profiling=1` in a mysql server window but that only works while queries are executed in that window.

I'm able to log queries without the timings by adding a line similar to "log=/path/to/log" in my my.cnf file.

What I want instead is mysql to produce a log file (as queries are executed) that shows the query and the amount of time spent on each query and the value can be similar to what is displayed in the `Duration` column when I execute `show profiles` in the mysql server window.

The queries are executed via mysqli calls in a PHP program which makes the back-end of a website. That's why I need the timings in a log file.

Does anyone know how I can make mysql produce such a log?

Comment: I once did this in PHP, set `microtime()` before start, and compare it with a new `microtime()` after the query. Query time was very identical from running it directly in MySQL to the result from `microtime()` comparison

Comment: That would then mean I'd have to search for all cases in my php code where a mysql call was made. I'm looking for a simpler solution than that. It could even be a setting I need to apply to mysql that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Depends on how you have it set up, I personally have one class that all queries go to, I only have to add it to a single function for it to take effect throughout an entire CRM that I've spent over a year designing. #planahead

Comment: Do you want to produce this because you have to? or want to? - Been doing this for 14 years and never had the need.

Comment: Both but more so need because I want to optimize web page speed loading time and due to the large number of pages, not all pages can be stored in cache so my only other option is to reduce query execution time

Comment: May I ask the genre of website you have, as I'm curious about the potential load you may have

Answer (score 0):

Look into

- The "general log" -- be cautious; it fills up disk fast.  (Or it can go to a table.)
- The slowlog, but with long_query_time=0 in order to catch everything.  Again it can be a disk hog.

Comment: Neither of those helped. I use MySQL v5.0.37 and I tried enabling slow log with query time of zero and I enabled the general log and neither showed the times. In fact the slow query log didn't fill with any queries but the general log did contain queries when I executed the webpage uncached.

Comment: Oh, 5.0 did not like long_query_time=0.  But it should like "1"; that will catch the slower queries.  "query_time" in the slow_log is the _elapsed_ time for the query.  And you should consider upgrading to 5.1 or 5.5 or (better yet) 5.6.  5.0.37 is 8 years old; the longer you wait, the more painful the upgrade will be.